# Executing Security Class(TokenAuthenticator) before Data-Dog/AuditBundle

Tags: php, symfony, audit-logging

I am using [Data-Dog/Auditbundle](https://packagist.org/packages/data-dog/audit-bundle) for AuditLogs in my symfony application.Also I have TokenAuthenticator as my guard for api's. But bundle's EventSubscriber is being called before TokenAuthenticator and hence

```
public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $securityTokenStorage)
{
    $this->securityTokenStorage = $securityTokenStorage;
}
```

this in EventSubscriber gives token as null and I am not able to getUser.

Comment: Can you show up your security.yaml? Especially the firewall covering the path for which the issue occurs, and the `access_controls`. Also I guess you are using Symfony 4.4 or higher, can you confirm?

Comment: Thanks! It worked by overriding default EventSubscriber of Bundle by my own EventSubscriber and extend few other functionalities in it.